# How to use Bresenham's line drawing algorithm with sub pixel bias?

Tags: algorithm, line, rasterizing, bresenham

[Bresenham's line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) is well known and quite simple to implement.

While there are more advanced ways to draw anti-ailesed lines, Im interested in writing a function which draws a single pixel width non anti-aliased line, based on floating point coordinates.

This means while the first and last pixels will remain the same, the pixels drawn between them will have a bias based on the sub-pixel position of both end-points.

In principle this shouldn't be all that complicated, since I assume its possible to use the sub-pixel offsets to calculate an initial `error` value to use when plotting the line, and all other parts of the algorithm remain the same.

> No sub pixel offset:

```
X###
    ###X
```

Assuming the right hand point has a sub-pixel position close to the top, the line could look like this:

> With sub pixel offset for example:

```
X######
       X
```

Is there a tried & true method of drawing a line that takes sub-pixel coordinates into account?

---

Note:

- This seems like a common operation, I've seen OpenGL drivers take this into account for example - using `GL_LINE`, though from a quick search I didn't find any answers online - maybe used wrong search terms?
- At a glance this question looks like it might be a duplicate of:
   [Precise subpixel line drawing algorithm (rasterization algorithm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679963)
  However that is asking about drawing a wide line, this is asking about offsetting a single pixel line.
- If there isn't some standard method, I'll try write this up to post as an answer.

Comment: I suppose might apply a fixed-point scaling factor and evalute the initial error term from the fractional part of the starting point. I can't see the benefit of Bresenham over easier algorithms though, say directly evaluating the function or a fixed-point DDA? Optimizing for the setup seems unlikely to be a win unless your average lines are tiny and I'd be hard-pressed to avoid taking a division in computing the error seed in any event.

Comment: While fixed-point DDA is probably a good solution, I'd like to be satisfied that applying bias to Bresenham's method as described in the question - is for some reason impractical. I can't really make too many assumptions about how many and what length the lines might be, but I would like to keep roughly the same performance, apart from a small speed hit from the initial setup.

Comment: I guess you'd seed with `e = frac(x1) * (y2 - y1) + frac(y1) * (x2 - x1)`, albeit with the coordinates in fixed-point to avoid the rounding errors. My point is that the DDA innerloop (basically an addition and a shift) is usually faster than Bresenham, with the drawback being a small initialization hit which is typically irrelevant unless your lines are very short or division exceedingly expensive.

Answer (score 8):

Having just encountered the same challenge, I can confirm that this is possible as you expected.

First, return to the simplest form of the algorithm: (ignore the fractions; they'll disappear later)

```
x = x0
y = y0
dx = x1 - x0
dy = y1 - y0
error = -0.5
while x < x1:
    if error > 0:
        y += 1
        error -= 1
    paint(x, y)
    x += 1
    error += dy/dx
```

This means that for integer coordinates, we start half a pixel above the pixel boundary (`error = -0.5`), and for each pixel we advance in `x`, we increase the ideal y coordinate (and therefore the current `error`) by `dy/dx`.

First let's see what happens if we stop forcing `x0`, `y0`, `x1` and `y1` to be integers: (this will also assume that instead of using pixel centres, the coordinates are relative to the bottom-left of each pixel<sup>1</sup>, since once you support sub-pixel positions you can simply add half the pixel width to the x and y to return to pixel-centred logic)

```
x = x0
y = y0
dx = x1 - x0
dy = y1 - y0
error = (0.5 - (x0 % 1)) * dy/dx + (y0 % 1) - 1
while x < x1:
    if error > 0:
        y += 1
        error -= 1
    paint(x, y)
    x += 1
    error += dy/dx
```

The only change was the initial error calculation. The new value comes from simple trig to calculate the y coordinate when x is at the pixel centre. It's worth noting that you can use the same idea to clip the line's start position to be within some bound, which is another challenge you'll likely face when you want to start optimising things.

Now we just need to convert this into integer-only arithmetic. We'll need some fixed multiplier for the fractional inputs (`scale`), and the divisions can be handled by multiplying them out, just as the standard algorithm does.

```
# assumes x0, y0, x1 and y1 are pre-multiplied by scale
x = x0
y = y0
dx = x1 - x0
dy = y1 - y0
error = (scale - 2 * (x0 % scale)) * dy + 2 * (y0 % scale) * dx - 2 * dx * scale
while x < x1:
    if error > 0:
        y += scale
        error -= 2 * dx * scale
    paint(x / scale, y / scale)
    x += scale
    error += 2 * dy * scale
```

Note that `x`, `y`, `dx` and `dy` keep the same scaling factor as the input variables (`scale`), whereas `error` has a more complex scaling factor: `2 * dx * scale`. This allows it to absorb the division and fraction in its original formulation, but means we need to apply the same scale everywhere we use it.

Obviously there's a lot of room to optimise here, but that's the basic algorithm. If we assume scale is a power-of-two (`2^n`), we can start to make things a little more efficient:

```
dx = x1 - x0
dy = y1 - y0
mask = (1 << n) - 1
error = (2 * (y0 & mask) - (2 << n)) * dx - (2 * (x0 & mask) - (1 << n)) * dy
x = x0 >> n
y = y0 >> n
while x < (x1 >> n):
    if error > 0:
        y += 1
        error -= 2 * dx << n
    paint(x, y)
    x += 1
    error += 2 * dy << n
```

As with the original, this only works in the (x >= y, x > 0, y >= 0) octant. The usual rules apply for extending it to all cases, but note that there are a few extra gotchyas due to the coordinates no-longer being centred in the pixel (i.e. reflections become more complex).

You'll also need to watch out for integer overflows: `error` has twice the precision of the input variables, and a range of up to twice the length of the line. Plan your inputs, precision, and variable types accordingly!

<sup>1: Coordinates are relative to the corner which is closest to 0,0. For an OpenGL-style coordinate system that's the bottom left, but it could be the top-left depending on your particular scenario.</sup>

Comment: That's a fantastic answer.

One little thing that tripped me is the mention of "top-left" of pixels. That assumes that the y axis is going down, which unfortunately was not the case for me.

Comment: @Jyaif Thanks; I added a note which either clarifies things or makes them more confusing! I originally wrote this for embedded hardware where the display used 0,0 for top-left, but I think the more common use is people using OpenGL-style coordinate systems inside an operating system, where it would indeed be bottom-left.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, with the addition of needing sub-pixel endpoints, I also needed to make sure [**all** pixels which intersect the line are drawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885806/all-points-crossed-by-a-line?rq=1).

I'm not sure that my solution will be helpful to OP, both because its been 4+ years, and because of the sentence "This means while the first and last pixels will remain the same..." For me, that is actually a problem (More on that later). Hopefully this may be helpful to others.

---

I don't know if this can be considered to be Bresenham's algorithm, but it is awful similar. I'll explain it for the (+,+) quadrant. Lets say you wish to draw a line from point (P<sub>x</sub>,P<sub>y</sub>) to (Q<sub>x</sub>,Q<sub>y</sub>) over a grid of pixels with width **W**. Having a grid width **W** > 1 allows for sub-pixel endpoints.

For a line going in the (+,+) quadrant, the starting point is easy to calculate, just take the floor of (P<sub>x</sub>,P<sub>y</sub>). As you will see later, this only works if Q<sub>x</sub> >= P<sub>x</sub> & Q<sub>y</sub> >= P<sub>y</sub>.

[image: endpoints floored]

Now you need to find which pixel to go to next. There are 3 possibilities: (x+1,y), (x,y+1), & (x+1,y+1). To make this decision, I use the 2D cross product defined as:

[image]

- If this value is negative, vector **b** is right/clockwise of vector **a**.
- If this value is positive, vector **b** is left/anti-clockwise of vector **a**.
- If this value is zero vector **b** points in the same direction as vector **a**.

To make the decision on which pixel is next, compare the cross product between the line **P**-**Q** [red in image below] and a line between the point **P** and the top-right pixel (x+1,y+1) [blue in image below].
[image: cross-product diagram]

The vector between **P** & the top-right pixel can be calculated as:
[image: BLUE vector calculation]

So, we will use the value from the 2D cross product:
[image: full cross product maths]

- If this value is negative, the next pixel will be (x,y+1).
- If this value is positive, the next pixel will be (x+1,y).
- If this value is exactly zero, the next pixel will be (x+1,y+1).

---

That works fine for the starting pixel, but the rest of the pixels will not have a point that lies inside them. Luckily, after the initial point, you don't need a point to be *inside* the pixel for the blue vector. You can keep extending it like so:
[image: vectors outside the current pixel]
The blue vector starts at the starting point of the line, and is updated to the (x+1,y+1) for **every** pixel. The rule for which pixel to take is the same. As you can see, the red vector is right of the blue vector. So, the next pixel will be the one right of the green pixel.

The value for the cross product needs updated for every pixel, depending on which pixel you took.
[image: dx dy]

Add **d<sub>x</sub>** if the next pixel was (x+1), add **d<sub>y</sub>** if the pixel was (y+1). Add both if the pixel went to (x+1,y+1).

This process is repeated until it reaches the ending pixel, (Q<sub>x</sub> / **W**, Q<sub>y</sub> / **W**).

All combined this leads to the following code:

```c
    int dx = x2 - x2;
    int dy = y2 - y1;
    int local_x = x1 % width;
    int local_y = y1 % width;
    int cross_product = dx*(width-local_y) - dy*(width-local_x);
    int dx_cross = -dy*width;
    int dy_cross = dx*width;

    int x = x1 / width;
    int y = y1 / width;
    int end_x = x2 / width;
    int end_y = y2 / width;
    while (x != end_x || y != end_y) {
        SetPixel(x,y,color);
        int old_cross = cross_product;
        if (old_cross >= 0) {
            x++;
            cross_product += dx_cross;
        }
        if (old_cross <= 0) {
            y++;
            cross_product += dy_cross;
        }
    }
```

Making it work for all quadrants is a matter of reversing the local coordinates and some absolute values. Heres the code which works for all quadrants:

```c
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;
    int dx_x = (dx >= 0) ? 1 : -1;
    int dy_y = (dy >= 0) ? 1 : -1;
    int local_x = x1 % square_width;
    int local_y = y1 % square_width;
    int x_dist = (dx >= 0) ? (square_width - local_x) : (local_x);
    int y_dist = (dy >= 0) ? (square_width - local_y) : (local_y);
    int cross_product = abs(dx) * abs(y_dist) - abs(dy) * abs(x_dist);
    dx_cross = -abs(dy) * square_width;
    dy_cross = abs(dx) * square_width;

    int x = x1 / square_width;
    int y = y1 / square_width;
    int end_x = x2 / square_width;
    int end_y = y2 / square_width;

    while (x != end_x || y != end_y) {
        SetPixel(x,y,color);
        int old_cross = cross_product;
        if (old_cross >= 0) {
            x += dx_x;
            cross_product += dx_cross;
        }
        if (old_cross <= 0) {
            y += dy_y;
            cross_product += dy_cross;
        }
    }
```

However there is a problem! This code will not stop in some cases. To understand why, you need to really look into exactly what conditions count as the intersection between a line and a pixel.

## When exactly is a pixel drawn?

I said I need to make that **all** pixels which intersect a line need to be drawn. But there's some ambiguity in the edge cases.

Here is a list of all possible intersections in which a pixel will be drawn for a line where Q<sub>x</sub> >= P<sub>x</sub> & Q<sub>y</sub> >= P<sub>y</sub>:

[image: all possible intersections]

- A - If a line intersects the pixel completely, the pixel will be drawn.
- B - If a vertical line intersects the pixel completely, the pixel will be drawn.
- C - If a horizontal line intersects the pixel completely, the pixel will be drawn.
- D - If a vertical line perfectly touches the left of the pixel, the pixel will be drawn.
- E - If a horizontal line perfectly touches the bottom of the pixel, the pixel will be drawn.
- F - If a line endpoint starts inside of a pixel going (+,+), the pixel will be drawn.
- G - If a line endpoint starts exactly on the left side of a pixel going (+,+), the pixel will be drawn.
- H - If a line endpoint starts exactly on the bottom side of a pixel going (+,+), the pixel will be drawn.
- I - If a line endpoint starts exactly on the bottom left corner of a pixel going (+,+), the pixel will be drawn.

---

And here are some pixels which do **NOT** intersect the line:
[image: invalid intersections]

- A' - If a line obviously doesn't intersect a pixel, the pixel will **NOT** be drawn.
- B' - If a vertical line obviously doesn't intersect a pixel, the pixel will **NOT** be drawn.
- C' - If a horizontal line obviously doesn't intersect a pixel, the pixel will **NOT** be drawn.
- D' - If a vertical line exactly touches the right side of a pixel, the pixel will **NOT** be drawn.
- E' - If a horizontal line exactly touches the top side of a pixel, the pixel will **NOT** be drawn.
- F' - If a line endpoint starts exactly on the top right corner of a pixel going in the (+,+) direction, the pixel will **NOT** be drawn.
- G' - If a line endpoint starts exactly on the top side of a pixel going in the (+,+) direction, the pixel will **NOT** be drawn.
- H' - If a line endpoint starts exactly on the right side of a pixel going in the (+,+) direction, the pixel will **NOT** be drawn.
- I' - If a line exactly *touches* a corner of the pixel, the pixel will **NOT** be drawn. This applies to **all** corners.

---

Those rules apply as you would expect (just flip the image) for the other quadrants. The problem I need to highlight is when an endpoint lies exactly on the edge of a pixel. Take a look at this case:
[image: misleading endpoint]

This is like image G' above, except the y-axis is flipped because the **Q<sub>y</sub>** < **P<sub>y</sub>**. There are 4x4 red dots because **W** is 4, making the pixel dimensions 4x4. Each of the 4 dots are the **ONLY** endpoints a line can touch. The line drawn goes from (1.25, 1.0) to (somewhere).

This shows why it's incorrect (at least how I defined pixel-line intersections) to say the pixel endpoints can be calculated as the floor of the line endpoints. The floored pixel coordinate for that endpoint seems to be (1,1), but it is clear that the line never really intersects that pixel. It just touches it, so I don't want to draw it.

Instead of flooring the line endpoints, you need to floor the minimal endpoints, and ceil the maximal endpoints minus 1 across both x & y dimensions.

So finally here is the complete code which does this flooring/ceiling:

```c
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;
    int dx_x = (dx >= 0) ? 1 : -1;
    int dy_y = (dy >= 0) ? 1 : -1;
    int local_x = x1 % square_width;
    int local_y = y1 % square_width;
    int x_dist = (dx >= 0) ? (square_width - local_x) : (local_x);
    int y_dist = (dy >= 0) ? (square_width - local_y) : (local_y);
    int cross_product = abs(dx) * abs(y_dist) - abs(dy) * abs(x_dist);
    dx_cross = -abs(dy) * square_width;
    dy_cross = abs(dx) * square_width;

    int x = x1 / square_width;
    int y = y1 / square_width;
    int end_x = x2 / square_width;
    int end_y = y2 / square_width;

    // Perform ceiling/flooring of the pixel endpoints
    if (dy < 0)
    {
        if ((y1 % square_width) == 0)
        {
            y--;
            cross_product += dy_cross;
        }
    }
    else if (dy > 0)
    {
        if ((y2 % square_width) == 0)
            end_y--;
    }

    if (dx < 0)
    {
        if ((x1 % square_width) == 0)
        {
            x--;
            cross_product += dx_cross;
        }
    }
    else if (dx > 0)
    {
        if ((x2 % square_width) == 0)
            end_x--;
    }

    while (x != end_x || y != end_y) {
        SetPixel(x,y,color);
        int old_cross = cross_product;
        if (old_cross >= 0) {
            x += dx_x;
            cross_product += dx_cross;
        }
        if (old_cross <= 0) {
            y += dy_y;
            cross_product += dy_cross;
        }
    }
```

This code itself hasn't been tested, but it comes slightly modified from my [GitHub project](https://github.com/user1pc/SubPixelLine) where it has been tested.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you want to draw a line from `P1 = (x1, y1)` to `P2 = (x2, y2)` where all the numbers are *floating point* pixel coordinates.

1. Calculate the true pixel coordinates of `P1` and `P2` and paint them: `P* = (round(x), round(y))`.
2. If `abs(x1* - x2*) <= 1 && abs(y1* - y2*) <= 1` then you are finished.
3. Decide whether it is a horizontal (true) or a vertical line (false): `abs(x1 - x2) >= abs(y1 - y2)`.
4. If it is a *horizontal* line and `x1 > x2` or if it is a *vertical* line and `y1 > y2`: swap `P1` with `P2` (and also `P1*` with `P2*`).
5. If it is a *horizontal* line you can get the y-coordinates for all the x-coordinates between `x1*` and `x2*` with the following formula:

   ```
    y(x) = round(y1 + (x - x1) / (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1))
   ```

   If you have a *vertical* line you can get the x-coordinates for all the y-coordinates between `y1*` and `y2*` with this formula:

   ```
    x(y) = round(x1 + (y - y1) / (y2 - y1) * (x2 - x1))
   ```

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a6z1b47f/) you can play around with, you can try different points on line 12.

Comment: Thanks for the demo, however its using entirely floating point maths. I was interested in using Bresenham's line drawing algorithm, using only integer arithmetic - except for the initial setup which will need to calculate a bias based on floating point values. As far as I can see - this should be possible. If my intuition is wrong its impossible/impractical - then perhaps this answer shows a better way.

Comment: Fixed the demo.